# What does it mean if a "variable or field" is declared void? Error message help

Tags: c++

variable or field `letterGrade' declared void. This error message is coming up on the last iteration of the function 'letterGrade'. Anyone have an idea why?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void letterGrade (int score, string& scoreLetter);
string scoreLetter;
int main()
{
    int score;
    char A, B, C, D, F;
    cout<<"Enter the grade: ";
    cin>> score;
    letterGrade (score, scoreLetter);
    cout<<"The letter grade is a(n) "<< scoreLetter<<".";
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
void letterGrade (score, scoreLetter)
{
     for (score >= 90)
     {
             scoreLetter = 'A';}
      if (score == 100)
     {
             scoreLetter.insert (1, "+");
     } 
     else if (8<=score% 10 && score% 10 <= 9)
     {
                   scoreLetter.insert (1, "+");
     else if (0<=score% 10 && score% 10 <=1)
     {
                   scoreLetter.insert (1, "-");
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean by ¨on the last iteration¨? Is there something else you haven´t shown us, like a return statement?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming this is homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't naming the types on the parameters of the definition of `letterGrade`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void letterGrade (score, scoreLetter)
{
   //...
```

In the function definition above, you forgot to specify the *types*. Mention the types as:

```
void letterGrade (int score, std::string & scoreLetter)
{             //  ^^^this    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^this
   //...
```

Don't forget to `#include<string>`.

---

Another problem is this:

```
 for (score >= 90)
```

The form of `for` should be this:

```
 for(initialization; condition ; increment/decrement/changing-some-value)
```

Example:

```
 for ( int i = 0 ;  i <= score ; i++)
```

Comment: ok when doing that I get the error message, "expected ';' before ')' token." What does this mean. It is indicating the error is in the first 'for' function.

Comment: I see, first time using for and I totally forgot how the parameters are supposed to work. @Doug T., duly noted. I just adjusted it and used an 'if' function. Thanks everyone, appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as the others said - fix the `letterGrade` definition:

```
                  vvv       vvvvvvvvvvvv
void letterGrade( int score, std::string& scoreLetter )
```

After that, fix the [**for**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b80153d8.aspx), it should be something like:

```
 for (; score >= 90; --score )
 {
  //..
 }
```

Also, note that you shadow the global `scoreLetter` in `letterGrade`

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually looping in the `letterGrade` function?

Most homework assignments like this only require an `if-then-elseif-else` ladder.

I suggest removing the `for` statement and replacing with an `if` statement.  If you decide you need to loop or repeat, restore the `for` statement.

A `for` loop would allow you to *traverse* a table of scores vs. grade strings:

```
struct Grade_Score
{
    unsigned int grade;
    const char * grade_text;
};

const Grade_Score grade_table[] =
{
    {100, "A+"},
    {90, "A"},
    {80, "B"},
    {70, "C"},
    {60, "D"}
};
const unsigned int NUM_GRADE_ENTRIES =
    sizeof(grade_table) / sizeof(grade_table[0]);

std::string Grade_To_Score(unsigned int grade)
{
    std::string score = "F";
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_GRADE_ENTRIES; ++i)
    {
        if (grade >= grade_table[i].grade)
        {
             score = grade_table[i].grade_text;
             break;
        }
    }
    return score;
}
```

A similar search can be performed using the `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound` functions.

**Edit 1:**
I suggest you replace `system("pause");` with something more portable like:

```
cout << "Press Enter to continue\n";
cout.ignore(10000, '\n');
```

Not all platforms support the `pause` command.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC for can be written with only the comparison, aka end condition, specified

```
for (a>b)
for (a=2; a>b)
for (a>b; a++)
```

Should all work providing we do the missing initialization or iterator elsewhere in the code.